# ZTE z837vl and Ubuntu OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, ubuntu-for-android, zte

(sorry I am pretty new user) I have an older mobile device that I was interested in switching the OS to Ubuntu. It's a ZTE Z837VL. If it's possible to achieve what's the best way to do it? Thanks

Comment: There are no supported official versions of Ubuntu that run on mobile phones.  Ubuntu Touch is no longer maintained by Canonical and is off-topic here.  ubports has taken up the project and it is supported only on the following list of devices: https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/

Comment: I don't think that Ubuntu Touch is off-topic. While it's not maintained by Canonical, it's maintained by part of the Ubuntu Community, it's still based on Ubuntu (and will continue to do be), UBports has a license (granted by Canonical) to use the brand, and UBports Community does follow the Ubuntu Code of Conduct, and does actively participate in Ubuntu Community activities.